# Does Gstreamer support the MP3 Surround format?

Tags: mp3, xine

I am curious if Gstreamer can handle playing MP3 surround files. I have a few, but I can't get anything special about the file in properties except that it has double the normal kbps (which is normal for files encoded with MP3sx). Anyway, if not, does Xine or libVLC support it? Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To my knowledge, it does. You can try your mp3s in Totem (Movie Player), and set the output to ac3 passthrough or which ever format best suites you:

[image]